# Unable to grab value from REST request

Tags: rest

I am trying to grab the Id of the last created item, but am unable to grab the value.  The query is correct as I can see it in the object but I'm getting an `invalid character` error when trying to use `JSON.parse(data.body)`.

Here's what I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MyPath/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Id&$orderby=Id%20desc&$top=1",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        console.log(jsonObject.d.Id);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON.error);    
    }
});
```

Where is the error being caused?  Or what is a better alternative in order to grab that Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed around the success to grab it from the array instead:

```
success: function(data) {
    var results = data.d.results;
    console.log(results[0].Id);
}
```

I am now able to grab that Id.